# Pregunta acerca de una Relación muchos a muchos en laravel

Tags: laravel

La duda radica  en una relación muchos a muchos, tengo la tabla devices , repairs y la intemedia device_repair. Lo que quiero es obtener todos los dispositivos acargo de un técnico apartir del modelo Repair,  ya que el id_ técnico se encuentra en esta tabla. 
Pero intento hacer un foreach para apartir del modelo y la relación  mostrar en el HTML algo como $device->devices ->'atributo' y obtener cada atributo que necesite al igual como en las otras relaciones, pero no he podido . Como lo puedo conseguir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voy a colocar el fragmento de una guia que hice para la relacion de muchos a mucho:

**Muchos a Muchos**

Esta  relación es la más complicada con la (uno a uno / uno a muchos) y consiste en que un elemento a puede contener muchos elementos b y a su vez un elemento b puede contener muchos elementos A.

Para su creación se necesita 3 tablas (tabla a, tabla b,  relacion_ab)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al igual que los otros modelos se debe crear un método para vincular la relación entre los datos.  El método usado se colocar dentro de las clases modelos (Ej: alumnos, clases), en este se colocara el siguiente código:

**PARA EL MODELO DE ALUMNOS**

```
belongsToMany('app\Clase', 'rel_alumno_clases', 'alumno_id', 'clase_id');
```

**Donde:**

**belongsToMany**   método empleado para la relación de muchos a muchos

**'app\Clase'** ruta  y nombre de la clase modelo  a la cual se vincula (Ej, Si el modelo que se construye el metodo es alumno entonces se coloca el modelo clases)

**'rel_alumno_clases'**  es el nombre de la tercera tabla intermedia que hace la relacion entre las otras dos tablas.

**'alumno_id'**  nombre de la llave foránea que vincula al id del tabla que maneja el modelo

**'clase_id'** nombre de la llave foranea que se usa para buscar los items que estan relacionado

**PARA EL MODELO DE CLASES**

```
belongsToMany('app\Alumno', 'rel_alumno_clases', 'clase_id', 'alumno_id');
```

El metodo usado es el mismo pero hay cambios en cuanto a modelo usado y se invierte el oriden entre las llaves foráneas.

**CREANDO MIGRACIONES**

**Migración para Alumnos:**

Comenzamos con la migración para la tabla alumnos para lo cual vamos a tipear el siguiente comando artisan indicándole el nombre de la tabla:

```
php artisan make:migration crear_tabla_alumnos --create=alumnos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Migración para Clases:**

Para la migración del archivo clases se tipea el comando artisan con el parámetro                        --create=clases para indicar que el nombre de la tabla.

```
php artisan make:migration crear_tabla_clases --create=clases
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Migracion de rel_alumno_clases**

La ultima migración es la correspondiente a la tabla rel_alumno_clases , para lo cual se tipeara el comando artisan:

```
php artisan make:migration crear_tabla_rel_alumno_clases --create=rel_alumno_clases
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITANDO ARCHIVO MIGRACION**

El siguiente paso es la colocación del código correspondiente para la construcción de las columnas en las tablas y sus relaciones.

Codigo de migración para **crear_tabla_alumnos**
El metodo **up()** en la migración es el siguiente:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('alumnos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Código de migración para **crear_tabla_clases**
El método **up()** en la migración es el siguiente:

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clases', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('clase');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Código de migración para **rel_alumno_clases.**

En el método **up()** se va a colocar la creación de las columnas y luego las relaciones.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rel_alumno_clases', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('alumnos_id')->unsigned();  // pone tipo int(10)
            $table->integer('clases_id')->unsigned();

            // FK relacion tabla alumnos
            $table->foreign('alumnos_id')->references('id')->on('alumnos');
            // FK relacion tabla clases
            $table->foreign('clases_id')->references('id')->on('clases');
        });
    }
```

**EJECUTANDO LAS MIGRACIONES**

El siguiente paso despues de hacer colocado el código en el metodo up() es la ejecución de la migración para crear las respectivas tablas, procedemos a tipear el comando.

```
php artisan migrate
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede apreciar que se han ejecutado correctamente las 3 migraciones correspondientes a la tabla.

**CREANDO LOS MODELOS**

Los modelos son creados antes de los seeder debido a que estos son necesarios para el manejo de las tablas y su población.

El primer modelo a crear es para la tabla alumnos tipeando el siguiente comando:
php artisan make:model Alumno

```
php artisan make:model Alumno
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente paso es indicarle al modelo Alumno que tipo de tabla se va usar ya que no se esta trabajando con las convenciones de nombres empleada por Laravel. 
(No se usa como nombre de tabla las convenciones Laravel)

```
<?php

namespace cursos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Alumno extends Model
{
    // indica al modelo cual tabla se va manejar
    protected $table = 'alumnos';
}
```

El siguiente Modelo a crear será el de Clase utilizando el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan make:model Clase
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido de esta Clase modelo va a ser el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace cursos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Clase extends Model
{
    // indica al modelo cual tabla se va manejar
    protected $table = 'clases';
}
```

El Ultimo modelo a crear corresponde a la tabla rel_alumno_clases, para lo cual tipeamos el comando:

```
php artisan make:model Rel_alumno_clase
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido de la clase modelo será el siguiente:

```
<?php

Namespace cursos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rel_alumno_clase extends Model
{
    // indica al modelo cual tabla se va manejar
    protected $table = 'rel_alumno_clases';
}
```

**CREANDO LOS SEEDER**

**Seeder AlumnosTableSeeder**

El Seeder que se va a crear a continuación es para la tabla alumnos usando el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan make:seeder AlumnosTableSeeder
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido de este Seeder va a ser el siguiente:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use cursos\Alumno;  // para llamar al modelo

class AlumnosTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // se usa un for para crear 9 registros de nombres de alumno
        for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
            Alumno::create([
                'name'      =>  'Alumno #' . $i
            ]);
        }
    } 
}
```

En el siguiente código se utiliza un bucle **for** para la población de la tabla alumnos la cual va a generar 10 registros (0 al 9) con datos para la columna name.

**Seeder ClasesTableSeeder**

El otros seeder a crear corresponde a la tabla clases, para lo cual se va a tipear el siguiente comando artisan:

```
php artisan make:seeder ClasesTableSeeder
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido de este seeder es el siguiente:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use cursos\Clase;  // para llamar al modelo

class ClasesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
         // se usa un for para crear 3 reg para fisica
         for ($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
            Clase::create([
                'clase'         =>  'Fisica #' . $i
            ]);
        }
        // se usa un for para crear 3 reg para Quimica
        for ($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
            Clase::create([
                'clase'         =>  'Quimica #' . $i
            ]);
        }
        // se usa un for para crear 3 reg para Matemática
        for ($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
            Clase::create([
                'clase'         =>  'Matemática #' . $i
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

El código del seeder contiene 3 bucles que permiten la creación de 3 registros diferentes por cada materia que son numerados del 1 al 3 en total van a ser 9 registro que serán almacenados en la tabla.

**Seeder rel_alumnoTableSeeder**

El último seeder a crear corresponde a la tabla que relaciona a las otras dos.

```
php artisan make:seeder rel_alumnoTableSeeder
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para asociar las tablas en una relación muchos a muchos debemos conocer el contenido de las tablas.

**Tabla: alumnos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Table: clases**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo: un alumno tiene varias clases

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo: una clase tiene varios Alumnos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cantidad en Relación:

Alumno #0 -> Fisica #1  Total 4
Fisica #1 - >Alumnos  Total 5

El código del archivo seeder para **rel_alumnoTableSedder.php** es el siguiente:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use cursos\Rel_alumno_clase;  // para llamar al modelo

class rel_alumnoTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // relacion muchos a muchos alumno -> clase
        Rel_alumno_clase::create([
            'alumnos_id' =>  '1',
            'clases_id' =>  '1'
        ]);
        Rel_alumno_clase::create([
            'alumnos_id' =>  '1',
            'clases_id' =>  '2'
        ]);
        Rel_alumno_clase::create([
            'alumnos_id' =>  '1',
            'clases_id' =>  '3'
        ]);
        Rel_alumno_clase::create([
            'alumnos_id' =>  '1',
            'clases_id' =>  '4'
        ]);
        // relacion muchos a muchos clase -> alumno *inverso
        Rel_alumno_clase::create([
            'alumnos_id' =>  '2',
            'clases_id' =>  '1'
        ]);
        Rel_alumno_clase::create([
            'alumnos_id' =>  '3',
            'clases_id' =>  '1'
        ]);
        Rel_alumno_clase::create([
            'alumnos_id' =>  '4',
            'clases_id' =>  '1'
        ]);
        Rel_alumno_clase::create([
            'alumnos_id' =>  '5',
            'clases_id' =>  '1'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**EJECUTANDO LOS SEEDER**

Primero se ejecuta el archivo seeder para **AlumnosTableSeeder** :

```
php artisan db:seed --class=AlumnosTableSeeder
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Segundo archivo a ejecutar es el de la  **ClasesTableSeeder**.

```
php artisan db:seed --class=ClasesTableSeeder
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tercer archivo a ejecutar  de seeder es rel_alumnoTableSedder

```
php artisan db:seed --class=rel_alumnoTableSeeder
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**COLOCANDO LA RELACION EN LOS MODELOS**

Los métodos que se necesitar para establecer la relacion se colocan en los modelos involucrados en la asociaion de las tablas como son Alumno y Clase.

**Clase Alumno:**  Se coloca el siguiente código como metodo para saber cuantas clases esta registrado el alumno.

```
// relacion muchos a muchos (alumnos -> clases)
     public function clases()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany('cursos\Clase', 'rel_alumno_clases', 'alumnos_id', 'clases_id');
     }
```

**Donde:**

**belongsToMany** es el metodo empleado para la relacion muchos a muchos

**'cursos\Clase'**  clase modelo que se relaciona con la clase Alumno

**'alumnos_id'** llave foránea que relaciona a la llave local id

**'clases_id'**  llave foránea que relaciona a la otra tabla que usa el modelo Clase

El otro paso es crear la relación inversa dentro de la clase modelo **Clase.php.**

```
// relacion muchos a muchos (alumnos -> clases)
    public function alumnos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('cursos\Alumno', 'rel_alumno_clases', 'clases_id', 'alumnos_id' );
    }
```

**PROBANDO LA RELACION CON TINKER (CONSULTA)**

Para realizar las pruebas del funcionamiento de la relacion vamos a ejecutar el comando tinker a fin de ejecutar una consulta con el modelo.

```
php artisan tinker
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tipeamos la siguiente sintaxis para ver el contenido del registro #1

```
$a=Alumno::find(1);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora hacemos la consulta de la relacion con agregando el metodo clases a la consulta

(nos debe mostrar 4 registros)

```
$a=Alumno::find(1)->clases;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta nos muestra todas las clases que esta inscrito el alumno 1

Contamos la cantidad de clases registras por el alumno 1.

```
$a=Alumno::find(1)->clases()->count();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el caso INVERSO donde queremos saber los alumnos que están inscrito en una clase determinada , tipeamos el siguiente comando:

```
$c=Clase::find(1);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora queremos saber cuántos alumnos están en la clase de Fisica #1.

(nos debe mostrar 5 registros)

```
$c=Clase::find(1)->alumnos;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Contamos la cantidad de Clases registrada Fisica #1 por alumnos

```
$c=Clase::find(1)->alumnos()->count();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para salir de tinker tipeamos el comando: **exit**

Answer (score 4):

En el modelo Repair debes asignar la relación.

```
public function devices(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Device', 'device_repair')
      }
```

Si has seguido la convencion de Laravel no deberías tener problemas. Lo que veo es que escribiste el nombre del campo de clave foránea como "id_tecnico" y deberías cambiarlo por "tecnico_id". En todo caso, si quieres mantener "id_tecnico", debes pasarlo como tercer argumento.

```
public function devices(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Device',  'device_repair', 'id_tecnico');
      }
```